# Web API has two controllers one works, one doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web, asp.net-web-api

I've got a web api with two controllers.  On localhost both work.  On live IIS 7.0, one works and the other returns "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '***'.

The controller that works is:

```
namespace DBTest.Controllers
{
  public class EmployeesController : ApiController
  {
    private GaryEntities1 db = new GaryEntities1();

    // GET api/Employees
    public IQueryable<EMPLOYEE> GetEMPLOYEES()
    {
        return db.EMPLOYEES;
    }

    // GET api/Employees/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(EMPLOYEE))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEMPLOYEE(int id)
    {
        EMPLOYEE employee = db.EMPLOYEES.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(employee);
    }

    // PUT api/Employees/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutEMPLOYEE(int id, EMPLOYEE employee)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != employee.EMPID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EMPLOYEEExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/Employees
    [ResponseType(typeof(EMPLOYEE))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostEMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE employee)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.EMPLOYEES.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.EMPID }, employee);
    }

    // DELETE api/Employees/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(EMPLOYEE))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteEMPLOYEE(int id)
    {
        EMPLOYEE employee = db.EMPLOYEES.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.EMPLOYEES.Remove(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(employee);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool EMPLOYEEExists(int id)
    {
        return db.EMPLOYEES.Count(e => e.EMPID == id) > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The one that doesn't is:

```
namespace DBTest.Controllers
{
  public class GPSController : ApiController
  {
    private GaryEntities1 db = new GaryEntities1();

    // GET api/GPS
    public IQueryable<GPS> GetGPS()
    {
        return db.GPS;
    }

    // GET api/GPS/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(GPS))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetGPS(int id)
    {
        GPS gps = db.GPS.Find(id);
        if (gps == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(gps);
    }

    // PUT api/GPS/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutGPS(int id, GPS gps)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != gps.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(gps).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!GPSExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/GPS
    [ResponseType(typeof(GPS))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostGPS(GPS gps)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.GPS.Add(gps);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = gps.Id }, gps);
    }

    // DELETE api/GPS/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(GPS))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteGPS(int id)
    {
        GPS gps = db.GPS.Find(id);
        if (gps == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.GPS.Remove(gps);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(gps);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool GPSExists(int id)
    {
        return db.GPS.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

To me, they look identical.  I think it about has to be an IIS problem on the server since it works fine on localhost.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How have you publish your second project? Is it the correct folder in IIS InetPub forlder?

Comment: Try renaming the `public IQueryable<GPS> GetGPS()` to `public IQueryable<GPS> GetAllGPS()`. It will still have the same address

Comment: The two controllers are in the same api.  And it works locally.  That's why I don't think it would be routing.  But, I'm stumped right now.  I did try changing the GetGPS() to GetAllGPS(), but got the same results.

Comment: On the deployment machine, try deleting all files before redeploying, and restart IIS

Comment: Deleting all files on production machine, then redeploying fixed it.  Thanks to all for the help, especially Cosmin.